# Spring batch-Circular reference error while using Java Beans but the application runs properly by using xml beans

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Bean "delegateItemWriter" and "itemWriter" have cyclic calls to each other.
When I comment xml bean(which runs fine) and run by using java beans it gives me error as "Requested bean is currently in creation".
Can anyone help why this is happening with java beans only and not for xml beans?
Any help would be appreciated.

Batch Job defination:

```
<job id="fileToFileWithHeaderFooterJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <step id="step">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="2">
                <streams>
                    <stream ref="delegateItemWriter" />
                </streams>
            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="itemWriter" />
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

If I comment below xml bean(delegateItemWriter) my application breaks and gives me error as **Error creating bean with name 'delegateItemWriter': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?**

```
<beans:bean id="delegateItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <beans:property name="resource" ref="outputFileResource" />
    <beans:property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <beans:property name="delimiter" value="," />
            <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <beans:property name="names"
                        value="newId,newName,newDate,newParty,newPrice" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="headerCallback" ref="headerCallback" />
    <beans:property name="footerCallback" ref="itemWriter" />
</beans:bean>


Java Config:

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Object> itemReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Object> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    DefaultLineMapper<Object> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

    lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"dealId", "price", "name", "party", "Date"});

    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new TradeDataFieldSetMapper());

    itemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("inputData.txt"));
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    return itemReader;
}

@Bean
public SimpleItemProcessor itemProcessor() {
    return new SimpleItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
    public FileToFileFooterCallback itemWriter(final ItemWriter<TradeDataOutput> delegetItemWriter) {
    FileToFileFooterCallback footerCallback = new FileToFileFooterCallback();
    footerCallback.setDelegate(delegetItemWriter);
    return footerCallback;
}


@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<TradeDataOutput> delegateItemWriter(final FileToFileFooterCallback itemWriter) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<TradeDataOutput> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    LineAggregator<TradeDataOutput> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    FieldExtractor<TradeDataOutput> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();

    String[] names = {"newID", "newName", "newDate", "newParty", "newPrice"};
    ((BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<TradeDataOutput>) beanWrapperFieldExtractor).setNames(names);

    ((DelimitedLineAggregator<TradeDataOutput>) delimitedLineAggregator).setDelimiter(",");
    ((DelimitedLineAggregator<TradeDataOutput>) delimitedLineAggregator).setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);

    writer.setLineAggregator(delimitedLineAggregator);
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(
        "batch/filetoFileWithHeaderFooterOutputFile.data"));
    writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
    writer.setHeaderCallback(new FileToFileHeaderCallback());
    writer.setFooterCallback((FlatFileHeaderCallback) itemWriter);
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `@DependsOn`?

Comment: As I want a "delegateItemWriter" bean from xml that's why.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why you're using the `@DependsOn` annotation.  Unless you have some form of initialization ordering requirement that Spring won't figure out automatically, I'd remove that annotation.

Comment: If I do remove @DependsOn annotation with above configuration, I get below error: **Error creating bean with name 'itemWriter': Requested bean is currently in creation**

Comment: I'm assuming `this.pipeline` is an application context?  If so, don't do that ;)  Have Spring inject the reference into the method instead.

Comment: If I remove ApplicationContext how can I get the bean from xml. And I want to remove my all the xml beans and need to create java beans. My application is running fine if I have only xml beans.

Comment: Two points: 1.  Your question states that you're converting the XML to java config so I'm assuming that the XML won't be there and 2.  Update your method to be like below and Spring will pass it in:
`public FileToFileFooterCallback itemWriter(ItemWriter<OutputFile> delegetItemWriter) {`

Comment: @MichaelMinella- I have updated my question. I need xml only for job defination. And I am not able to make up running "delegateItemWriter" using java bean, that is why I put it in xml.

Comment: 1.  I see no reason why you can't move that bean definition to java config.  2.  How are you bootstrapping your ApplicationContext?

Comment: 1. I have moved it to java config, but as in java bean def for **itemWriter** it needs **delegateItemWriter** and vice versa. which depends on each other, so the result is error: "Requested bean is currently in creation".
2. I am using spring's CommandLineJobRunner for bootstrapping my appContext.

Comment: Ah....sorry, I didn't realize your footer callback was the parent in this case.  In that case, don't define the delegate as a separate bean in your java config.  Just use one method to build it all.

Comment: Please see my footer callback in delegateItemWriter which points to itemWriter bean. Though I write one method for delegateItemWriter but still I will face the same issue..

Comment: Is this project available somewhere in Github?  A PR against this would be much faster...

Comment: :( no it's not available in Github..